# Window.location.href lost after default ngRoute redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this simple Angular app with ngRoute, a single route defined and the default redirecting to the same (in index.html):

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.location = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf('#'));
});

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/page', { 
          controller: 'PageController', 
          templateUrl: 'page.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ 
          redirectTo: '/page' 
        }); 
});

app.controller('PageController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

});          
</script>


<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

The page.html displays the $rootScope.location:

```
{{$root.location}}
```

When I access the page with by using directly `index.html#/page`, it shows the location as expected, but when accessing it by just `index.html` and then it redirecting me to `index.html#/page`, the `$rootScope.location` remains empty.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: probably because page is NOT reloaded so actual `window.location.href` is NOT updated so neither does `$root.location`, the routing takes place inline the page without reloading the page, or changing the hash. Maybe by using other method instead of `.otherwise` which as far as i can tell is a fallback

Comment: @NikosM. Then I think it may have the value from the initial page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, I find it.

`window.location.href.lastIndexOf('#')` returned -1 while accessing it via `index.html` and the statement returned a substring from 0 to -1 which is empty.